# R ggplot2: how to make x-axis lines not overlapping y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, axis

I often produce charts from ggplot, and I like to have a light design (white background etc.)
This all works fine except that the x-axis lines are overlapping the y-axis lines, see red markings in the screenshot:

[image: overlapping axis, marked red]

what I would like is shown below and at the moment, I have to edit every plot in Illustrator... I would like that the x-axis does not overlap the y-axis lines (not on the right and not on the left side). In my opinion, this looks much cleaner.

[image: what i want]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I haven't found anything up to now... so any help is greatly appreciated.

***EDIT (example):***

the data:

```
                                    label_de proz
 1:                        Dialekt / Sprache 37.6
 2:                               Landschaft 52.1
 3: Traditionen und Bräuche (Fasnacht, etc.) 20.4
 4:             Siedlungsraum (Gebäude usw.) 21.6
 5:   Sportclubs (Fussball, Eishockey, etc.) 13.4
 6:                     Freunde und Bekannte 61.7
 7:                                  Familie 57.0
 8:                 Bewohnerinnen / Bewohner 14.9
 9:   Kulinarisches Angebot (Essen, Trinken) 12.2
10:                          Freizeitangebot 18.6
11:                       Politisches Profil  5.8
12:                                  Anderes 13.1
```

and the ggplot-code (without ordering):

```
p <- ggplot(data=ggdata, aes(x=label_de, y=proz)  ) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() + theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
                                        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                                        panel.border = element_blank(),
                                        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                                        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                                        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                                        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1),
                                        legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: added it - hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a way to do this without editing the grid grobs manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `expand= c(0,0)` to the scale, and then move the labels so they aren't chopped. Example with random data

```
set.seed(123)
ggplot(data=data.frame(label_de=letters[1:10], proz = runif(10,0, 85)),
       aes(x=label_de, y=proz)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  coord_flip() + 

  # notice this part
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
         axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1),

         # notice this part
         axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1),
         legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: very nice and truly helpful, only thing now is that the "proz"-axis labels are moved a bit to the left...

Comment: Yes, that's because the plot now ends immediately with the right-most vertical grid line. If the labels were centered below their ticks, part of the '100' would be chopped off. Right-aligning them (which has the effect of moving them a bit left) was my quickie solution to this problem.